# Data GA after resetting Client ID

Tags: google-analytics, clientid

I was wondering what would happen with the data after you reset a cookie.

For example, someone visits your website and gets a random Client ID. He logs in and you change the Client ID to his Webiste Client Id. What will happen with the pageviews and data before you change the cookie? Will GA see this visitor as two different visits? One with the former Client ID and one with the new User ID?

Is this similar to what will happen with the not yet introduced User ID?

Answer (score 0):

If the `_ga` client cookie is deleted, GA considers them a new visitor on any subsequent visit.

Similar question answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7805934/794336

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10109891/794336